# Building regex based on str objects in a loop

Tags: python, regex, loops

I have a list containing texts that I want to combine into a single string object. However, I want to edit the text while importing it: for the first page, I want to delete everything before the 'marcacao_comeco', and for the last page, I want to delete everything after the 'marcacao_fim'. However, the re.sub function doesn't seem to work with Python objects. I created the following example to demonstrate the problem. I need to build the regex constantly since I'm doing this for many documents.

```
page1 = ' Once upon a time, there was a little girl named Lily who lived in a small village at the foot of a mountain.'
page2 = 'One day, while she was walking in the forest, she stumbled upon a hidden cave.'
page3 = 'Lily saw a bear, who had already spotted her. Trembling with fear, Lily thought it was the end. But to her surprise, the bear did not attack her. Instead, it led her safely out of the forest'

pages = [page1, page2, page3]

marcacao_comeco = 'girl named'
marcacao_fim = 'the bear did not attack her.'

final_text = ''

for i, page in enumerate(pages):
    if i == 0:

        regex_inicio = re.escape(marcacao_comeco) + r'.*\n'
        page = re.sub(regex_inicio, '', page)
    
    elif i == len(pages) - 1:
        regex_fim = r'\n.*' + re.escape(marcacao_fim)
        page = re.sub(regex_fim, '', page)

    else:
        page = page
    
    final_text = final_text + page

final_text
```

The output that I got just concatenated the pages. I wish my output would start with 'girl named Lily who lived in a small village at ...'  and end with '... the bear did not attack her.'

Comment: None of the texts contains a newline.

Comment: Since no answer yet, I'll post 2 regexes you can try (I'm no regex expert). `regex_inicio = rf"^.*(?={re.escape(marcacao_comeco)})"` and `regex_fim = rf"(?<={re.escape(marcacao_fim)}).*$"`. The first one uses [Positive Lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/uPZqWA/1) and the second one uses [Positive Lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/IWvevj/1) to not include the texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. As pointed out in the comments, your strings do not contain a `\n`, so your regexes would fail to match anything.
If you remove the `\n` from your code, you will find that your regexes will match some of your text, but it will replace with `''` exactly what you intended to keep.

My approach is to work with groups, so for each line you will divide it into a group which you will delete, and a group which you'll keep. For example, I will build the first regex to be `(.*)(girl named.*)`, so it will match the whole string and divide it into `$1` (everything before the string you want to keep), and `$2` (the remainder of the string, starting from `girl named`). Instead of replacing with `''`, we'll replace with the group you want to keep, that is, `$2`. In python, you'll want to use `'\g<2>'` to represent the second group. For the last page, you have keep the first group and remove the second, so we'll need to tweak the regex a bit.

This is the fixed loop, based on the approach explained above:

```
for i, page in enumerate(pages):
if i == 0:
    regex_inicio = r'(.*)(' + re.escape(marcacao_comeco) + r'.*)'        
    page = re.sub(regex_inicio, '\g<2>', page)
    
elif i == len(pages) - 1:
    regex_fim = r'(.*' + re.escape(marcacao_fim) + r')(.*)'
    page = re.sub(regex_fim, '\g<1>', page)

else:
    page = page
```